# Stable way to find QR-decomposition

Tags: matrices, algorithms, matlab, matrix-decomposition, octave

How to compute the QR decomposition of matrix 
\begin{bmatrix} v^T \\ QR \end{bmatrix}
in a stable way,
where $QR$ represent the product of a real orthogonal matrix $Q \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ and upper triangular matrix $R \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ and $v \in \Bbb R^n$ is a vector?

I am allowed to use Matlab or Octave to solve this problem but I am not sure what would be a stable way to do this? I understand that $QR$ is already a product of required matrices, but I cannot come up with any idea to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golub and Van Loan's [Matrix Computations](http://web.mit.edu/ehliu/Public/sclark/Golub%20G.H.,%20Van%20Loan%20C.F.-%20Matrix%20Computations.pdf) is the standard reference. Chapter 7 presents a number of algorithms for the QR decomp and discusses stability of those algorithms.

Comment: I did not find this one in particular though. I understand how to do QR decomposition otherwise